# Add Ui element?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using LightningChartJs and would like to add UI elements like arrows at the ends of a line series and would also like to write or annotate something on top of the line.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current API, it is possible to add text on the chart by using *chart.addUiElement()* API to add a *UITextBox*.

```
chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox)
```

The textBox doesn't use the same scale as the Series do, however, so they will not track the position if you're zooming or panning the view.

We are planning on adding annotations as a new feature in the future.